# java: when running jar file from icon Runtime.getRuntime.exec() doesn't work

Tags: java, windows-7, jar

so I have this problem. I have an aplication, which is using `Runtime.getRuntime.exec(adobePath)` to run Adobe Reader. 
When I run my aplication using NetBeans or from cmd line by using `java -jar "MyApp.jar"` it does work fine. But when I run jar file by double-click or from cmd using `MaApp.jar` it doesn't work. I'm using Windows 7.

What can be wrong?

Thanks

edit: Maybe I said it wrong way. When I run jar file by double-click it does run. And it works, but when `Runtime.getRuntime.exec(adobePath)` is called nothing happens. And It work fine in NetBeans or when I run App by `java -jar "MyApp.jar"`.

Answer (score 0):

> Right-click on the jar and see under Open With ?
>
> Make  Java Runtime as default program to run with.